# Changing the windows wallpaper in pure java,

Tags: java, windows

Can anyone help me change my (*windows xp*) desktop wallpaper with pure java code,
 I have copied the two programs below from stackoverflow answers, but they are not working,
(i don’t understand them),or give me a link where I can learn about this code,

**the first one:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.UINT_PTR;
import com.sun.jna.win32.*;

public class WallpaperChanger {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //supply your own path instead of using this one
      String path = "C:\\w.jpg";

      SPI.INSTANCE.SystemParametersInfo(
          new UINT_PTR(SPI.SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER), 
          new UINT_PTR(0), 
          path, 
          new UINT_PTR(SPI.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPI.SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE));
   }

   public interface SPI extends StdCallLibrary {

      //from MSDN article
      long SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20;
      long SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
      long SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

      SPI INSTANCE = (SPI) Native.loadLibrary("user32", SPI.class, new HashMap<Object, Object>() {
         {
            put(OPTION_TYPE_MAPPER, W32APITypeMapper.UNICODE);
            put(OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, W32APIFunctionMapper.UNICODE);
         }
      });

      boolean SystemParametersInfo(
          UINT_PTR uiAction,
          UINT_PTR uiParam,
          String pvParam,
          UINT_PTR fWinIni
        );
  }
}
```

It removes the wallpaper, but it never changed it, I am getting a black desktop,

**the second:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class changer {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String wallpaper_file = "C:\\w.jpg";
        changer mychanger = new changer();
        mychanger.Change(wallpaper_file);
    }


    static {
        Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary("user32");
        //System.loadLibrary("user32");
    }

    public int Change(String path) {
        return SystemParametersInfo(20, 0, path, 0);   //my error //
    }

    public static native int SystemParametersInfo(int uiAction, int uiParam,
            String pvParam, int fWinIni);


}
```

In this code, I am getting an error on that line: ***return SystemParametersInfo(20, 0, path, 0);***

Comment: What is the error from the second piece of code?

Comment: Do you actually have an image file called `w.jpg` in the root of your `C` drive?

Comment: @ajp15243 in eclipse *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: changer.SystemParametersInfo(IILjava/lang/String;I)I*

Comment: JNA is not pure Java. It uses JNI under the hood so you will have to bundle different native libraries per platform with your application.